# Changing the side of a cube to a circle

Tags: modeling

I need to change the side of a cube to a circle. The object must show the gradual metamorphis from one shape to another. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to change all the side faces or just one? How sholud the end result look? Do you have some reference pictures or videos that explain what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add a cube & press <kbd>tab</kbd> to go into *Edit Mode*. Select these vertices:

[image]

2. <kbd>RMB</kbd> -> subdivide -> 3 cuts (or whatever you like)

[image]

[image]

3. In *Object Mode*, go to *Object Data Properties* -> *Shape Keys* and press the <kbd>Numpad+</kbd> two times:

[image]

4. Press <kbd>tab</kbd> again to enter *Edit Mode*. Then go to menu *Mesh* -> *Transform* -> *To Sphere* -> 1 (shortcut: Windows: <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> or Mac: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)

[image]

[image]

5. press <kbd>tab</kbd> to return to *Object Mode* -> now you can animate the cube with the value field here:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's so helpful. I gotta create a handle for a product and this is the key that I needed.

Answer (score 1):

1-Create a cube, add a subdivision surface modifier set to **simple** , the level viewport of 4 or 5.
[image]

2- Apply the modifier using the drop-down menu or ctrl+A.

[image]

3- Click the "green triangle" properties, and add two shape keys with the + button. make sure "Key 1" is selected.
[image]

4- press Tab to go to edit mode. Select all with A. Press F3 to open the search menu. Type "To Sphere" and choose it from the list. Then drag your mouse until it becomes a (almost) perfect sphere. Click Tab to exit edit mode.
[image]

5- By changing the *value* it changes shape.
[image]

6- (A quick tip) To give it a simple animation, instead of a number for the value, type #frame/30

and then press Space to play the animation.
[image]

Comment: The question says circle, not sphere...

Comment: Right, no problem. It could still be useful.

Comment: That was a great segway that I'll think I'll use in the near future. Thank you.

Comment: @BarbodM People will search for a solution to the actual question and see this "answer", so yes, there is a problem.