# how to move part of my object

Tags: animation

I am just beginning with blender so please forgive my ignorance in advance.
I have a very simple question. How I can move a part of my object i.e. I want to move just the lower part of my cube in direction x.

---

Actually, this is what I want to do in Blender. Movement of lower part of my object in x-direction. [image]

Comment: everybody started at some day learning blender...but for the very basic things, i would recommend watching these free beginner tutorials: https://www.blender.org/support/tutorials/

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248321/changing-the-side-of-a-cube-to-a-circle/248322#248322

Comment: you need to switch to Edit mode, select the bottom vertices with a select tool and press GX to move on X